# How to use the dxfgrabber or ezdxf package to find the area of a solid model from a DXF file

Tags: dxf

I am trying to use dxfgrabber to find the area of a solid model in dxf. Is there a function in dxfgrabber or ezdxf that looks up the area of the solid model from the dxf file?

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as many times before (search stackoverflow), dxfgrabber and ezdxf do not provide higher level functions, they are just interfaces to DXF.

Special case 3DSOLID/BODY/SURFACE/REGION: this entities are embedded [ACIS](http://www.spatial.com/products/3d-acis-modeling) models, you can get the ACIS/SAT data by dxfgrabber or ezdxf but that is all, 
for more you need licensed software of Spatial Corp.